# how can I apply different images to an auto filled table cell

Tags: php, pear

I am using pear HTML_TABLE to create a table display from a database. Because there are empty fields I am using the auto fill to fill in empty cells with an image. However, I need a different image for the alternating columns. This is the code that generates the empty cells:

```
    $attrs = array( 'class' => 'main', 
                    'id' => 'main_id',
                    'width' => '100%',
                    'border' => '1',
                    'cellspacing' => '0',
                    'cellpadding' => '0');
    $table = new HTML_Table($attrs);
    $table->setAutoGrow(true);
    $table->setAutoFill("<span class='iconImg'></span>");
```

I have tried using javascript, and jquery to accomplish this, but without success. The javascript (jquery) i have tried is:

```
    $(".main td:not(.jobCell):not(.tJCell)").each(function(){ 
    var colIndex = $(this).cellPos().left;
        var preCol = colIndex % 2;

        if (preCol == 0)
        {
            $(this).text( 'Even');
            //$(this).attr( 'src', '../images/buttons/list.png');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).attr( 'src', '../images/buttons/btn_pointer.png');
        }
    });
```

The above javascript is fine for placing odd or even as text in each cell. The problem is that I don't need text, I need an image, as in the else statement. I believe the code is correct, but it does not work.
I have even tried doing this with css, but the following css doesn't work either.

```
.iconImg
{
    background-image:url(../../images/buttons/list.png);
}
```

All help and/or advice in this matter would be greatly appreciated! I have been stuck on this for too many days now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the hopes that this will help others. My solution is based on cweiske's answer/suggestion. Since I could not get the css odd/even functionality to work, I used the following jquery script to assign a class to my auto filled cells:

```
$(".main td:not(.jobCell):not(.tJCell)").each(function(){ 
            var colIndex = $(this).cellPos().left;
                var preCol = colIndex % 2;

                if (preCol == 0)
                {
                    $(this).addClass('evenCell');
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).addClass('oddCell');
                }
            });
```

The above function is reference code written by nrodic. This was used because I have colspans and rowspans throughout my table (which throws off cell indexing), and the empty cells between are auto filled with using pear HTML_TABLE auto fill like this:

```
$attrs = array( 'class' => 'main', 
                'id' => 'main_id',
                'width' => '100%',
                'border' => '1',
                'cellspacing' => '0',
                'cellpadding' => '0');
$table = new HTML_Table($attrs);
$table->setAutoGrow(true);
$table->setAutoFill("");
```

Then the resulting css code is this:

```
.evenCell
{
    background:url(../../images/buttons/btn_pointer.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:center;

}
.oddCell
{
    background:url(../../images/buttons/btn_list.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Hope this is helpful to others!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CSS even-odd rules](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd) to assign background images to the cells, as long as they have some class.

Comment: Thanks, That was my thought too. The problems is that I don't seem to be able to apply a class to the td its self. The small piece of generated html is what is created from the pear html_table extension. The class or id (if i assign an id) is placed inside the td element and therefore not an attribute of the td its self. Any attempts to use the class result in nothing. Any other suggestions, or something I may be missing?

Comment: You could autofill a span tag with a class and set the background image on that, together with the parent td's even/odd selector.

Comment: I have added a class which I can access, but I still cannot get it display the image. I used the odd even css rules, but all attempts result in an empty cell.

Comment: I posted the final code that actually accomplished what I needed. I'm sure there is another way to do this, but this is what I had to do to make it work. Your suggestion was very helpful!